# Pass router history to component for onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to clean my React app up a little with Container and Presentation components. I'm using **react-router v4** and I previously used an onClick event for each `job` to show a specific job page:

```
<div onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/jobs/' + job.slug)}>
  //The job info
</div>
```

Now I've created a dumb component in a separate file for the jobs like this:

```
const Jobs = (props) => (
  <div>
  {
    props.jobs.map(job =>
      <div key={job.slug} onClick(//todo)>
        <p>{job.title} at <Link to="/">{job.company}</Link></p>
      </div>
    )
  }
  </div>
)
```

but I can no longer access `this.props.history`

How can I solve this issue? Should I pass another prop in the following:

```
<Jobs jobs={jobs}/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To access router objects(`match`, `history` and `location`) via props of the component, either the component has to be rendered via Route or it should wrap with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher-order component.

Check whether your Jobs component is directly rendered via Route with something like this.

```
<Route path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
```

If it's not the case, and Jobs component is rendered with JSX inside the render method of another component, then wrap it with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher-order component as follows before you export it.

```
export default withRouter(Jobs);
```

This will ensure that Jobs component has access to all the router props.

Also, make sure that you use `props.history` instead of `this.props.history` since now it's functional component.

Comment: Thanks. `Jobs` is not directly rendered via Route. It's a const in a separate file as shown. Is it not possible like this?

Comment: How do you render `Jobs`? without looking at that can't say anything about that.

Comment: `Jobs` is called from within the `render()` method of the Container component.

Comment: I have used withRouter as you suggested and `this.props.history` isn't recognised.

Comment: Since now `Jobs` is functional component `this.props` doesn't work. Use `props.history` instead. `props` is the first argument of the functional component.

Comment: @tommyd456 you're welcome! I'll update the answer as well.

Comment: Would you say this is a "better" approach than passing a function as a prop to be used in the component?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. In fact, it's officially documented. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html